# GORM insert into wrong table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am reading from table P1 and writing to table Trade, and I find `gorm` is reading from table P1 and writing to table P1 which causes errors.

Error: `2020/11/16 14:56:50 /main.go:47 cannot convert 0 to Timestamptz [0.491ms] [rows:10969] INSERT INTO "p1" () VALUES ()`

I tried debug and I found it is inserting to `p1`.
[image]

I tried to force the table to `Trade` and I found I successfully changed the table names to `Trade` but the columns are of `P1`.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func initDB() {
    var err error
    //user=postgres
    dsn := "dbname=xxx port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Trade{}, &P1{})
    db = db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true)
}

func main() {
    initDB()

    var p1 []P1
    db.Find(&p1)

    in := false
    for _, r1 := range p1 {
        if in == false {
            in = true

            t := Trade{
                Pair1:     r1.Pair1,
                Pair2:     "xxxx",
                Direction: "Short",
            }

            db.Create(&t)
            return
        }
    }

}

type P1 struct {
    Time  time.Time
    Pair1 string
    Pair2 string
}

type Trade struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Pair1     string
    Pair2     string
    Direction string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in `db = db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true)`. Comment out this line. Issue resolved.